# SQL Query Missing 0 Counts

Tags: sql

I am trying to find the count of questions asked by user, including zero values. This query  retrieves counts of questions asked by users where count is greater than zero, but excludes zero counts. How can I edit it so that it also includes zero counts?

```
         select public.challenges_participations.user_id
              , count(public.questions.question_id) 
           from public.questions
left outer join public.challenges_participations
             on public.questions.user_id = public.challenges_participations.user_id
          where public.challenges_participations.challenge_id ILIKE 'pl%'
       group by public.challenges_participations.user_id
              ;
```

Comment: Does the user_id exist in the left table?  If it does, then you'll get a null record.  If not, you won't get anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

This because of the WHERE predicate on left-joined table column which prohibits NULL

```
where public.challenges_participations.challenge_id ILIKE 'pl%'
```

Include it into ON clause

```
on  
 public.questions.user_id=public.challenges_participations.user_id
 and public.challenges_participations.challenge_id ILIKE 'pl%'
```

BTW Aliases can make your sql much more readable.